# Macbook Air 2017 display turning off and on while using built in keyboard and mouse

Tags: mac, display, thunderbolt

[image: image of console errors]My macbook air was working fine until recently I used a Thunderbolt cable to mirror my Mac on my tv. From then on my Macbook's display started turning off then randomly on using the built in keyboard or trackpad and gets backs on by pressing any key. it only happens when i use my built in keyboard or trackpad but not when i use my USB mouse and keyboard. Please help me solve this. I have a Macbook air 2017 running macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

Comment: Try just pressing down on the top case (area around the keyboard and track pad). Does it still exhibit the same problem?

Comment: it helped to wake up my display for the time it was off. But the same issue happened again it was not a permanent solution

Comment: It’s not a solution, it’s diagnostics.   What happens, exactly?

Comment: what happens is that the display goes off and then when i press a key or press the area around it automically turns up

Comment: it is not like that that the problem occurs the whole day. It is like that the issue occurs for a hour then for another one hour the issue won't be there